# How to decode TPMS FSK signal on Universal Radio Hacker

Tags: sdr, fsk, manchester-coding, bpsk

I am capturing the TPMS sensor transmission in URH, but i am having extremely hard time to decode correctly the signal.

I know exactly what is the data string that my real sensor is transmitting and i also know from the supplier that the sensor uses an Infineon SP37T chip, which transmits up to 10kbit/s. The supplier said they use FSK modulation, but looking the signal seems some phase shifting too. This is the string my sensor sends (in Hex):

54 50 56 2C A7 00 2C **00 0F** 2C **00 66** 2C **00 20** 2C 00 00 2C 00 **45** 2C 00 FF 2C 00 **51** 0D 0A
00 0F 00 66 00 20 is the sensor ID.
45 is the temperature and 51 is CRC.

I cannot decode right in URH, probably the many parameters on decoding are not correct.

**[HERE](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1o770ebulVYlI7tNPwD2W-CBnaDLvOb2J/view?usp=share_link)** are some samples i recorded with URH. The string transmitted is the same, but they look slightly different because i was trying different gains, antennas, sample rate and also tried with HackRF and RTL-SDR.
I have noticed that the sensor sends 2 different blocks of data, not sure exactly why. For sure it is not a repetition. First may be a preamble(?).
Appreciate if someone helps to make the decoding match the known data.

Comment: Just to complement, the sensor IC SP37T uses one of the following encoding:
- Manchester
- Inverted Manchester
- Differential Manchester
- Biphase 0
- Biphase 1
- Chip Mode (NRZ)

Comment: Have you read the data sheet for the device you mention?

Comment: @Andyaka yes, but it doesn't go down so deep on these encoding/modulation details, unfortunately. I think the key information should be the transmission baud rate so i can determine how many samples per bit and also the encoding type, which is one of the ones i informed above. These modes are taken from SP37T IC datasheet. This is determined by firmware, which i don't have access. Thanks!